# Build failed when i run react native in ANdroid studio

Tags: react-native

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "node" (in directory "E:\ReactNative\SanDream\android"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score -1):

Running it from the shell worked for me. `cd` into SanDream/android then run `npx react-native run-android`